# Related to limit superior of a sequence if sequence doesn't converge

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that I have a sequence $(a_n)$,and I am interested in finding the $\lim_{n\to \infty}$sup$(a_n)$.So I have the following definition of limsup of a sequence:
$c_n$ =sup{$b_n$,$b_{n+1}$,$b_{n+2}$,.....,...}
$c_{n+1}$=sup{$b_{n+1}$,$b_{n+2}$,$b_{n+3}$,.....}
...     .....  .....   .... ....... ...... 
..... ..... ..... .... .....
$c_m$=sup{$b_m$,$b_{m+1}$,$b_{m+2}$,.....}
So $\lim_{m\to \infty}$sup$(b_m)$=$\lim_{m\to \infty}$$(c_m)$ 
,

I know that in case limit of a sequence exists ,it has to be equal to its point of convergence.So in this case ,I can find out limsup.
But how can one find out limsup if limit of a sequence doesn't exist?????.

There is one more definition of limsup:The smallest  no. L$\in$$\mathscr R$ with the property that there are at most finitely many terms in the sequence larger than L+$\varepsilon$ $\forall$ $\varepsilon$$\gt$$0$,is said to be limsup of the sequence 

How are the above two definitions equivalent???? Please help me at the earliest.I'll be highly obliged to you..-_-

Comment: The two definitions are not (yet) equivalent because you've misquoted the second one.  It should say that $L$ is the **smallest** number with the property that you described.

Comment: Oops ! yes yes of course! Thanks

Comment: Even then how are they equivalent????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that there is no general way of calculating the limit of a sequence, there is no general way to calculate the limes superior of a sequence. This entirely depends on the sequence itself.

To see a simple example, consider $a_n = (-1)^n$. Then obviously $|a_n| = 1$, so that $c_n \le 1$ for all $n$. But since $a_{2n} = 1$, you actually have $c_n = 1$, so the limes superior is $1$.

The equivalence of the two characterizations is a typical proof that can be found in a first semester analysis lecture. To show that two numbers $a$ and $b$ are equal, you can equivalently show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ the inequalities $a \le b + \epsilon$ and $b \le a + \epsilon$ hold.

Fix an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ and set $L = \inf \{l \mid \{n \mid x_n > l + \delta\} \text{ is finite for all } \delta > 0\}$. Then by definition the set $\{n \mid x_n > L + \epsilon\}$ is finite, so let $N_0$ be the maximum of this set. This means $x_n \le L + \epsilon$ for all $n > N_0$, which implies $c_n \le L + \epsilon$ for all $n > N_0$. Therefore $\limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} c_n \le L + \epsilon$.

The other direction works in a smimilar fashion, using the definition of the infimum of a set.